# Django forms from "Generic related" models

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have some models, connected with `GenericForeignKey`:

```
Class Main(models.Model)
    filed_1      = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    object_id    = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object       = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

Class Additional_1(models.Model):
    f_1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    f_2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)

Class Additional_2(models.Model):
    d_1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    d_2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

And forms for this models:

```
Class MainForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
           model  = Main
           fields = ('filed_1', 'object_id', 'content_type')

           widgets = {
               'object_id': forms.HiddenInput,
               'content_type': forms.HiddenInput
           }

Class Additional_1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model  = Additional_1
        fields = ('f1', 'f2')

Class Additional_2Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model  = Additional_2
        fields = ('d1', 'd2')
```

How to make forms, composed of fields of `MainForm` + `Additional_iForm` in one html form  with one submit button (`MainForm` + `Additional_1Form` and `Main` + `Additional_2Form`) and provide correct creating and editing. There is way to do it using standard Django components, like inline formset for `ForeignKey`?

P.S. I think the answer to this question should be contained in this section of the documentation, but there is too little information to answer. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-in-forms-and-admin

**EDITION #1**

```
# This is always false, because of 'object_id' in main_form
if main_form.is_valid() and additional_1_form.is_valid():
    additional = additional_1_form.save()
    main_form.object_id = additional .id # I need something like this to set object_id 
    main_form.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one form tag:

```
<form action="..." method="POST">
{{ main_form }}    
{{ additional_form_1 }}    
{{ additional_form_2 }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

where `{{ mainform }}`, `{{ additional_form_1 }}` and `{{ additional_form_2 }}` are the HTML that Django generates for each of each of the forms. You can add editing feedback or additional functionality using JavaScript (such as filling in values when the user has selected a particular value for a particular field).

In the back-end, you can then check whether each of the forms is valid:

```
if (main_form.is_valid() and
   additional_form_1.is_valid() and
   additional_form_2.is_valid()):
   pass
```

If not, you can display errors in the form page again.

Comment: Thanks, but how to create/edit models? For create i need first save Additional form and then pass the saved model to Main form to tie models through "generic relation", right?

Comment: @Deadly: why do you wish to pass the model to the form again? If you have the information from each of the three forms and they are all valid then you can perform the proper saving operations in the back-end (where I currently have `pass` after the if statement).

Comment: Because to save `MainForm` i need to know `object_id` field, which will be known only after Additional model has been saved (pk). And there is another problem: `MainForm` always invalid, because `object_id` field unknown before saving of additional model, but required in the `MainForm.fields` tuple, to make `MainForm.save` method works correct. I have added view code into the question and have edited class `MainForm`.